# Check 'Manager can update membership list' in AD

Tags: .net, powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to find a way with PowerShell (no Quest or Exchange CmdLets) to check if the box 'Manager can update membership list' on an active directory group object is marked or not.

[image]

So far I've found a [blog article](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/blur-lines_-powershell_-author_shirleym/2013/10/07/manager-can-update-membership-list-part-1/) that comes really close, but it's only setting the value using .NET. Other posts are using [LDAP](https://serverfault.com/questions/118625/how-to-set-or-clear-manager-can-update-membership-list-using-powershell) and [dsacls](http://ad-directory.blogspot.de/2012/08/ad-group-managedby-update-powershell.html) to set this value.

The only thing I'm looking for is reading this value to have a `$True` or `$False`. But I'm not really good at .NET, so any help is really appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

The following .NET code is used to create the rule:

```
$Rule = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule ($sid, `   
[System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryRights]::WriteProperty, `
[System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow, `
[Guid]"bf9679c0-0de6-11d0-a285-00aa003049e2")
```

This makes me believe that it should be possible to read `[System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryRights]` and/or `[System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]` to see if this value is set.

Anyone who knows how this can be done?

Comment: I'm currently facing the same problem.. This check box is not listed in the Attribute Editor, so I don't think you'll find a value with `True` or `False`. Did you manage to tick the Checkbox using the TechNet blog script?

Comment: I don't have write permissions in our AD because of group restrictions. That's why I'm only looking to read the value... It should be possible with .NET I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I figured it out, for anyone else interested this did the trick for me:

```
Function Test-ADGroupManagerCanUpdateHC {
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS 
        Test a group in AD to see if it has 'Manager can update membership list' enabled or not.

    .DESCRIPTION 
        Test a group in AD to see if it has 'Manager can update membership list' enabled or not.
        In case it is enabled (checked) we will return an object, in case it's not the output will
        be false and nothing will be returned.

    .PARAMETER DistinguishedName 
        The distinguished name of the object.
        Ex: 'CN=Yellow babanas,OU=Groups,OU=FRUITS,OU=WORLD,DC=domain,DC=com'

    .PARAMETER UseLDAP
        In case this switch is used we use 'LDAP' and the active directory module isn't required.

    .EXAMPLE 
        Test-ADGroupManagerCanUpdateHC 'CN=Yellow babanas,OU=Groups,OU=FRUITS,OU=WORLD,DC=domain,DC=com'
        When there no output, then the user defined in 'ManagedBy' can not update the membership list.
    #>

    [CmdLetBinding()]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory,ValueFromPipeline)]
        [String]$DistinguishedName,
        [Switch]$UseLDAP
    )

    Begin {
        Function Convert-SidToNTAccountHC {
            Param (
                [String]$IdentityReference
            )

            Try {
                $Sid = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($IdentityReference)
                $Sid.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])
            }
            Catch {
                # User's SID can't be translated as he is probably deleted
                $Global:Error.Remove($Global:Error[0])
            }
        }
    }

    Process {
        Try {
            foreach ($D in $DistinguishedName) {
                if ($UseLDAP) {
                    $ADObject = [ADSI]"LDAP://$D"
                    $Acl = $ADObject.PSBase.ObjectSecurity
                    $AclRules = $Acl.GetAccessRules($true,$true,[System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])
                }
                else {
                    $AclRules = (Get-Acl -Path AD:$D).GetAccessRules($true,$true,[System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])
                }

                $Objects = foreach($A in $AclRules) {
                    [PSCustomObject]@{
                      'DistinguishedName'     = $D
                      'ActiveDirectoryRights' = $A.ActiveDirectoryRights
                      'ObjectType'            = $A.ObjectType
                      'InheritedObjectType'   = $A.InheritedObjectType
                      'AccessControlType'     = $A.AccessControlType
                      'IdentityReference'     = $A.IdentityReference
                      'NTAccount'             = Convert-SidToNTAccountHC $A.IdentityReference
                    }           
                }

                $Result = $Objects | where {($_.ObjectType -eq 'bf9679c0-0de6-11d0-a285-00aa003049e2') -and 
                    ($_.InheritedObjectType -eq 'bf967a9c-0de6-11d0-a285-00aa003049e2') -and 
                    ($_.ActiveDirectoryRights -like '*WriteProperty*') -and
                    ($_.AccessControlType -eq 'Allow') -and
                    ($_.NTAccount)}

                if ($Result) {
                    Write-Verbose "Manager can update the membership list of group '$D'"
                    $Result
                }
                else {
                    Write-Verbose "Manager can not update the membership list of group '$D'"
                }
            }
        }
        Catch {
            throw "Testing for 'Manager can update membership list' on '$D' failed: $_"
        }
    }
}
```

I tested this on several groups and it seems to work perfectly. Please let me know if you see something that I might have missed.

Comment: It does not work for me. I checked and unchecked the box and it always says Manager can NOT update...

Answer (score 0):

I've made a script which selects a collection of groups, checks it and export it. Look int the comments for your changes.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
<# If you want to select all Distribution Groups uncomment this and comment row 4
add-pssnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010 #For Exchange 2010
groups =  Get-DistributionGroup -ResultSize Unlimited 
#>
$groups =  Get-Group -RecipientTypeDetails UniversalDistributionGroup # !! Change to the groups you need
$output = @()
$ManagerCanUpdate = ""
Function Test-ADGroupManagerCanUpdateHC {
Begin {
    Function Convert-SidToNTAccountHC {
        Param (
            [String]$IdentityReference
        )

        Try {
            $Sid = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($IdentityReference)
            $Sid.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])
        }
        Catch {
            $Global:Error.Remove($Global:Error[0])
        }
    }
}

Process {
        $AclRules = (Get-Acl AD:$DistinguishedName).GetAccessRules($true,$true,[System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])
        $Objects = foreach($A in $AclRules) {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                'DistinguishedName'     = $DistinguishedName
                'ActiveDirectoryRights' = $A.ActiveDirectoryRights
                'ObjectType'            = $A.ObjectType
                'InheritedObjectType'   = $A.InheritedObjectType
                'AccessControlType'     = $A.AccessControlType
                'IdentityReference'     = $A.IdentityReference
                'NTAccount'             = Convert-SidToNTAccountHC $A.IdentityReference
            }         
     }
        $Result = $Objects | where {($_.ObjectType -eq 'bf9679c0-0de6-11d0-a285-00aa003049e2') -and 
                ($_.NTAccount -eq $ManagedByLogin) -and 
                ($_.ActiveDirectoryRights -like '*WriteProperty*') -and
                ($_.AccessControlType -eq 'Allow')}

        if ($Result) {
            $obj.ManagerCanUpdate = "True"
            Write-Host "Manager can update the membership list of group '$DistinguishedName'"    
        }
        else {
            $obj.ManagerCanUpdate = "False"
            Write-Host "Manager can not update the membership list of group '$DistinguishedName'"
        } }
}

foreach ($value in $groups){
$obj = "" | select "Name","OU","ManagedBy","ManagerCanUpdate" # !! - Change if you need other attributes - !!
$DistinguishedName = $value.DistinguishedName
$obj.Name = $value.Name
$obj.OU = $value.OrganizationalUnit
$ADGroup = [ADSI]"LDAP://$DistinguishedName"
$ManagedBy = $ADGroup.Properties["managedBy"]
if ($ManagedBY -ne ''){
$ManagedByUser = [ADSI]"LDAP://$ManagedBy"
$ManagedByLogin = "YourDomain\" + $ManagedByUser.Properties["sAMAccountName"] # !! - Change to your domain (Should look like: DM\username) !! - 
Test-ADGroupManagerCanUpdateHC
$obj.ManagedBy = $ManagedByLogin
}
else {
$obj.ManagedBy = "N/A"
$obj.ManagerCanUpdate = "N/A"
}   
$output += $obj
$obj = $null
$groups = $null
$ManagerCanUpdate = $null
}
$output | export-csv -Path Your_Path\output.csv -NoTypeInformation  # !! Change Path !!
```